# How to link multiple primary keys to one application?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I dont think the questions does this situation justice. But I am pretty new with programming and I would appreciate any help with my situation.

Basically, I am designing a "help ticket" system. Where people can find a product via DDL list, highlight the appropriate column and submit a ticket. The DDL is listed by ProductID and Productname. However, I have grouped several product ids together in the same column to make it easier for the user.

Now the user can fill out a ticket, send it, and I will receive it. The program itself is using c#, microsoft visual studio 2010,ajax, sql server from godaddy --> stored procedures that are linked to sql datasources, the tickets are stored in a gridview and onclick will display the ticket info, the error message pops up when the ticket is associated with more than one ProductID. Tickets associated with one productID work fine. The javascript will display the ticket info and uses ajax to call a webmethod. I believe the errors lie somewhere in the SQL and webmethod. Am I not calling the ProductID correctly? How can I associated one ticket with multiple ProductIDs? I believe I have to link the concept that multiple ProductIDs can have one ProductName but I am not sure how to go about doing that.

Anyone who can shed any light on the matter would be greatly appreciated. I will be active on this page so I will get back to questions fast and post things that are needed. Thank you!!

```
[WebMethod]
public TicketDetails GetTicketDetails(string TicketCode)
{
    vw_TicketDetailsTableAdapter ta = new vw_TicketDetailsTableAdapter();
    DataSets.vw_TicketDetailsDataTable dt = ta.usp_vw_TicketDetails_GetTicketDetailsByTicketCode(TicketCode);
    TicketDetails ticket = new TicketDetails();
    if (this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false)
    {
        ticket.ErrorMsg = "Authentication Failed!";
        return ticket;
    }
    ticket.ProductName = dt[0]["ProductName"].ToString();
    ticket.ProductVersion = dt[0]["ProductVersion"].ToString();
    ticket.PCINumber = dt[0]["PCICatalogID"].ToString();
    ticket.IssueHeader = dt[0]["IssueHeader"].ToString();
    ticket.IssueDescription =  dt[0]["IssueDescription"].ToString();
    ticket.Name = GetPersonalInfo(TicketCode, "Name");
    ticket.Email = GetPersonalInfo(TicketCode, "Email");
    ticket.SendEmail = GetPersonalInfo(TicketCode, "SendEmail");
    ticket.TicketCode = dt[0]["TicketCode"].ToString();
    ticket.ResolutionDescription = GetResolution(dt[0]["IssueID"].ToString());
    ticket.PhoneNumber = GetPersonalInfo(TicketCode, "PhoneNumber");
    ticket.ResolvedKBArticle = dt[0]["ResolvedKBArticle"].ToString();

    return ticket;
}
```

Comment: It's difficult to discern what the problem is from your post. Is there an error message of any kind, or is it a logic problem?

Comment: Also, were you aware that [Microsoft says: ASMX Web Services are a “Legacy Technology”](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/07/03/microsoft-says-asmx-web-services-are-a-%E2%80%9Clegacy-technology%E2%80%9D/)

Comment: I don't get the line "However, I have grouped several product ids together in the same column to make it easier for the user.". Could you provide an example?

Comment: Heres an example of a column::
    AGS343, AGS344, AGS345  Math Problem 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you give some details on your datamodel? What you probably need is a linker entity between the tickets and the products?

[image]

Comment: You are probably right, this is a database issue. Give me a couple minutes.